# Open/Edit/Save from on the host with app running in container

Tags: docker

We recently have a lot of problem deploying the Linux version of our app for the client (*updated libraries, missing libraries, install path*), and we are looking to use Docker for deployment.

Our app as a UI, so we naturally map that using

```
-e DISPLAY:$DISPLAY -v /tmp/X11-unix:/tmp/X11-unix
```

and we can actually see the UI popping up.

But when it's time to open a file, the problem start there. We want to only browse the host system and save any output file on the host (*output directory is determined by the location of the opened file*).

Which strategy would you suggest for this?

We want the client to not see the difference between the app running locally or inside Docker. We are working on a launch script so it looks like the client would still be double-clicking on it to start the app. We can add all the configuration we need in there for the *docker run* command.

Answer (score 1):

After recommendations by @CFrei and @Robert here's a solution that seems to work well:

```
docker run                                \
       -ti                                \
       -u $(id -u):$(id -g)               \
       -v /home/$(id -un):/home/$(id -un) \
       -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd         \
       -w $(pwd)                          \
       MyDockerImage
```

And now, every file created inside that container is perfectly located in the right directory on the host with the ownership by the user.

And from inside the container, it really looks like the host, which will be very useful for the client.

Thanks again for your help guys!

And I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, the container hast its own filesystem that is provided by the image where it runs on top.

You can map a host's directory or file to a path inside the container, where your program expects it to be. This is known as docker volume. You're already doing that with the X11 socket communication (the `-v` flag).

For instance, for a file:

```
docker run -v /absolute/path/in/the/host/some.file:/path/inside/container/some.file
```

For a directory:

```
docker run -v /absolute/path/in/the/host/some/dir:/path/inside/container/some/dir
```

You can provide as many `-v` flags as you might need.

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) you can find more useful information.

Comment: I was thinking about mapping the location where the container is launched to a directory inside the container. But I'm not sure that would work for the Open Dialog window when the client is selecting a file to open. If he goes up one directory, he's back in the container. I was thinking of mapping "-v /:/mnt/host" in the hope that he would not go back beyond that point. But giving the container full access like this is risky.

Comment: It seems a risk at a first glance. But, how it would be different than installing your app directly in the host? You can run your container app as an specific user-name. (But, yes, It sounds risky anyway)

Comment: please keep in mind that the container runs by default as root. So all files created have root access (only). You can change the user with `docker run `-u ...`. You might want to include then also `-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd` to have your username in your container.